# Jquery - incluir variáveis na ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Antes de perguntar vou deixa o meu script:

**Html**

```
</form>
  <input type="text" id="email">
  <input type="password id="senha">
  <button>Entrar</button>
</form>
```

**Jquery**

```
 var form = $('form');
 var email = $('#email');
 var senha = $('#senha');

    form.submit(function(event)({
      event.preventDefault();
      $.ajax({
        url: 'verificar.php',
      )}
    )}
```

Como posso fazer para que o *verificar.php* leia os valores do *email e senha*. Dei uma pesquisada e pode ser feita pela Data, como posso fazer?

Answer (score 0):

Você pode modificar o seu script para este:

```
$('form').on('submit', function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();

  var email = $('#email').val();
  var senha = $('#senha').val();

  $.ajax({
    url: 'verificar.php',
    type: 'POST', /** Altere para  'GET' se o método de requisição for GET. */
    data: {
      email: email,
      senha: senha
    }
  });
});
```

**Nota:** sugiro que você leia  a API do jQuery para os seguintes métodos:

- [`jQuery.ajax`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) (para efetuar requisições AJAX);
- [`.val()`](http://api.jquery.com/val/) (para obter o valor de um elemento).

Answer (score 0):

Em vez de usar `id`s nos campos do formulário, você pode usar `name` e usar o método [`.serialize()`](https://api.jquery.com/serialize/), que irá retornar todos os campos numa string a ser enviada pelo Ajax para a página PHP.

Observe que seu formulário existem alguns erros de digitação:

```
</form> <- aqui o form foi fechado em vez de ser aberto
  <input type="text" id="email">
  <input type="password id="senha"> <- aqui faltou aspas para fechar o type
  <button>Entrar</button>
</form>
```

Usando `name` e corrigindo os erros acima, seu formulário ficaria assim:

```
<form>
  <input type="text" name="email">
  <input type="password" name="senha">
  <button>Entrar</button>
</form>
```

Usando o `.serialize()`:

```
var dados = form.serialize();
```

A variável `dados` passa a ter os valores dos campos do formulário, como por exemplo:

```
email=email@dominio.com&senha=senha_digitada
```

Aplicando no `submit` e Ajax com o método POST:

```
var form = $('form');

form.submit(function(event){
   event.preventDefault();

   var dados = form.serialize();

   $.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      data: dados,
      url: 'verificar.php',
      success: function(data){
         // faça alguma coisa se o Ajax foi bem sucedido;
      }
   });
});
```

No arquivo PHP `verificar.php`, você captura os valores com:

```
<?php
$email = $_POST['email'];
$senha = $_POST['senha'];
?>
```